# browser popup in windows authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, windows-authentication

I'm using the windows authentication for get the name of the user using:
User.Identity.Name;

If the user is external to the domain the browser (not my site) shows a popup for the login.
and after that is showed the my login page.
I don't want it.

I want that if the user isn't logged, is showed a my page html for the login.
How can i do it?

The web.config has

```
<authentication mode="Windows">
      <forms name="login" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" defaultUrl="~/Default.aspx" timeout="30000" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
<allow users="*" />
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you really want is Forms Authentication where the form will authenticate to your Active Directory. Take a look at this link on MSDN:

[Building Secure ASP.NET Applications: Authentication, Authorization, and Secure Communication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa302397)

As far as I know the forms tag you have in there is only for Forms authentication as per the MSDN documentation here: [Authentication tag documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/532aee0e%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).